# Convexity of a twice differentiable function with restricted domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Consider the function $f: (\mathbb{R}^+)^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x_1 x_2$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables) all I have to do in order to determine if $f$ is convex is computing the Hessian and checking if it's positive semi-definite. The Hessian of $f$ is

$ H =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

and it is not positive semidefinite, because

$ x^t H x =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
= 2x_1x_2$

is negative for
$ x' =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}$. However $x' \notin (\mathbb{R}^+)^2$ is not in the domain of $f$ and actually we have

$\forall x \in (\mathbb{R}^+)^2: x^t H x > 0$

### Question

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. Which of the following statements is true?

- $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$ convex if and only if $\forall x \in C: x^t H x \geq 0$.
- $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$ convex if and only if $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^t H x \geq 0$.

Comment: Both are true. The first is more restrictive than the second

Comment: @JayaramIyer My example shows how both statements cannot be true at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the statement you want:

Let $f : \mathcal D \to \mathbb R$ be twice differentiable with $\mathcal D \subset \mathbb R^n$ convex and open. Then $f$ is convex on $\mathcal D$ if and only if its Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is positive semi-definite for all $x \in \mathcal D$. That is, if for all $x \in \mathcal D$ and all $u \in \mathbb R^n$, $u^\top \nabla^2 f(x) u \geq 0$.

Notice the distinction between the Hessian at $x$, where $x$ must be in the domain, and the $u$ in the definition of positive definiteness. The latter should be considered as directions and live in $\mathbb R^n$.

In your example, $\mathcal D = (0,\infty)^2$ and the Hessian at $x \in \mathcal D$ is not positive definite. Therefore the function $f(x, y)$ is not convex on the given domain.